# Java: issues relocating Canvas that's drawn into a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe, location

I can't get my Canvas to be drawn in the centre of my `JFrame`. My hope is to draw an image to the `JFrame` that will have a fancy border, then the `Canvas` will sit in the centre of the `JFrame`. I've tried `canvas.setLocation(Point p)` and `canvas.setBounds(Rectangle r)` and `Canvas.setLocation(int x, int y)` and I can't get any of them to work. I also tried the following before calling `game.frame.pack()`:

```
game.frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
game.frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This is the setup for the Canvas:

```
public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension((frameWidth * scale), frameHeight * scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    Game.game = this;
    //draw game items
    ....
}
```

Then this is the `JFrame` set up, which is done during the main method:

```
game = new Game();
    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setUndecorated(true); //Enable for full screen
    game.frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //Doesn't work
    game.frame.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Doesn't work
    //game.frame.add(game); //Just calling this doesn't work
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    //Window listener exitListener
    ....

    game.frame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);
    game.frame.requestFocus();
    game.start();
```

Also tried this:

```
    game = new Game();
    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setUndecorated(true); //Enable for full screen
    game.frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    game.frame.add(game, new GridBagConstraints());
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Which does nothing. Full code is [here](https://github.com/ritcat14/GotYourSix/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ritcat14/GotYourSix/Game.java), it is too much to post in the space of a question.

Thanks for you're help

Comment: Why your Game class doesn't extend at least JComponent? where are your painting methods?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Game class extends `Canvas`, and my painting is done in the render methods via the game loop. It is all handled by my `Screen` class

Comment: @AdminHydra, again you posted a few random lines of code. Without seeing the context of how the code is used in your application we can't help. Post a proper `SSCCE`. We don't know what all your variables represent. Create a simple panel and give id a preferred size and a background color and then add the panel to a frame using a GridBagLayout. You will see the panel is centered which is a proof of concept. If your real code doesn't work then you are doing something that we don't know about. Make an effort is you want help.

Comment: `Full code is here, it is too much to post in the space of a question` - you were never asked for the full code. We are not here to do the debugging for you. It is up to you to simplify the problem so you can see where you made your mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't get my Canvas to be drawn in the centre of my JFrame.

The easiest way to do this is to use a `GridBagLayout` instead of a `BorderLayout`:

```
game.frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
game.frame.add(game, new GridBagConstraints());
```

Read up on the weightx/weighty contraints as described in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to understand why this works.

Comment: added this: `game.frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`
                  `game.frame.add(game, new GridBagConstraints());` http://imgur.com/f7BVCOX -> doesn't work

Comment: @AdminHydra, yes it does, I use it all the time. Create a simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to test the concept. Once you get the simple SSCCE working you then figure out why your real code works differently. Posting a picture doesn't help us. Post a proper `SSCCE` if you need more help.

Comment: so you want me to answer my own question? I've asked for an answer that works. Providing me with an answer that would work if I fix my problem I've asked about defeats the point of asking the question.

Comment: @AdminHydra, `so you want me to answer my own question?` I want your to take the time to understand the suggestion. You didn't even bother to read the tutorial link I gave you. I gave you an answer that works!!!.  It is only two lines of code to get it to work properly!!! If it doesn't work then the problem is somewhere else in your code. You posted a few random lines of code. I am not a mind reader, I can't guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: added the edits i made based on your answer to my question. Now you can see exactly what i'm doing

Comment: if you'd like the full code, https://github.com/ritcat14/GotYourSix/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ritcat14/GotYourSix/Game.java

Comment: No, we are not here to debug your code. It is up to you to make an effort. You have been given the solution. First test the solution with a simple 15 line program to prove the concept works, Then look at your code to see what you are doing differently.